# How to update a SQL Server table with updated Oracle table Data

Tags: sql-server, openquery

I am using SQL Server (and Oracle as a linked Server).

The task involves updating the SQL Server table with any new changes to the column NAME in the Oracle TABLE.

EMP is PK and NAME is the column that can change.

ORACLE TABLE = TABLE1:

```
EMP                  NAME                
-------------------- --------------------
1                    JOE               
2                    David               
3                    BOB
```

SQL SERVER TABLE = TABLE1:

```
EMP                  NAME                
-------------------- --------------------
1                    JOE               
2                    David               
3                    FRED
```

**Code which is not working (runs and runs w/o updating):**

```
 UPDATE OC 
    SET    OC.NAME = MS.NAME
    FROM   OPENQUERY(ORCL12,
      'select EMP, NAME from TEST1') OC 
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[TEST1] MS 
     ON MS.EMP = OC.EMP
```

Comment: You're updating the Oracle server `OC` instead of `MS`.

Comment: tweaked the code and it is working, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @elizabk, here's the answer.

```
UPDATE MS 
    SET    MS.NAME = OC.NAME
    FROM   OPENQUERY(WZ12,
      'select EMP, NAME from Test') OC 
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[TEST1] MS 
     ON OC.EMP = MS.EMP
```

*Note: This was originally an edit to the original question. I just moved it here. @elizabk if you want to post your response, I'll delete this one.*

Comment: I posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the Oracle server `OC` instead of the SQL Server table `MS`.

```
UPDATE MS 
    SET    MS.NAME = OC.NAME
    FROM   OPENQUERY(WZ12,
      'select EMP, NAME from Test') OC 
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[TEST1] MS 
     ON OC.EMP = MS.EMP
```

Comment: OP needs to accept your answer. You're not allowed to delete an accepted answer.. @pthfndr2007